# Why does this Jasmine test fail occasionally in Firefox

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, firefox, global-variables, jasmine

EDIT: I changed my `console.log` to an `alert` and found the property: `getInterface`.

We have an environmental integrity test that ensures that our code does not introduce unwanted global variables. Before running our code, we create a "copy" of the `window` object:

```
var testingWindow = {};
for (var x in window) {
    if (window.hasOwnProperty(x)) {
        testingWindow[x] = true;
    }
}
```

And then after running our code, we run this test:

```
describe('After the program has run', function() {
    it('no new global variables have been introduced', function() {
        for (var x in window) {
            if (window.hasOwnProperty(x)) {
                if (!testingWindow[x]) {
                    console.log(x);
                }
                expect(testingWindow[x]).not.toBe(undefined);
                expect(window.hasOwnProperty(x)).toBe(true);
            }
        }
    });
});
```

This test passes in all browsers except Firefox. Even more odd, I have never seen the test fail with the `console` open, so any attempt to "see" the error has been futile. Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems like a Firefox bug: https://github.com/visionmedia/mocha/issues/380.

When I wrap this conditional around my `expect`s, they always pass:

```
if (x !== 'getInterface') ...
```

It looks like Firefox does not define `getInterface` at first, then it does later on. Having `console` open makes it defined at the beginning.